# Valgrind not detecting memory leak in threaded c++ program in raspberry pi

Tags: c++, multithreading, raspberry-pi3, valgrind, memory-leak-detector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <stdlib.h>
void *liveDataPush(void *);
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    pthread_t liveDataPushThread;
    int  RetThrd;
    void *ptr;
    RetThrd=pthread_create(&liveDataPushThread,NULL,liveDataPush, ptr);
    if (RetThrd != 0)
    {
        cout << "RetThrd" << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        int *j = (int *)(malloc(1024 * sizeof(int)));
        cout << "Hi" << endl;
        //free(j);
    }
    pthread_join(liveDataPushThread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
void *liveDataPush(void *)
{
    int *i = new int;
    *i = 30;
    //delete i;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        int *j = new int[1024];
        cout << "Hello" << endl;
        //delete[] j;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I have stored this program in raspberry pi board and trying to generate memory leak errors using valgring in putty terminal.
I tried :

```
gcc  -Wall -pedantic -g valgrind.cpp -o vlgrnd -pthread -lstdc++
```

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./vlgrnd
```

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=20 --track-fds=yes ./vlgrnd
```

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0 --leak-check=full ./vlgrnd
```

with (in another putty terminal)

```
gdb ./vlgrnd
target remote | vgdb

monitor leak_check full reachable any
```

None of them are detecting memory leak.

Using pthread_t along with #include thread, pthread_create, -pthread(during gcc compile) is causing "valgrind --leak-check=yes ./vlgrnd" not to return HEAP, LEAK and ERROR SUMMARIES.[valgrind output without SUMMARIES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWlDT.png) If we remove(comment out) thread related keywords and call thread as normal function and compile without pthread, then valgrind commands return SUMMARIES.
[valgrind output with SUMMARIES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aZCu.png)
My question is what is the valgrind command that producet memory leak errors for this program

Comment: what is your question? why are they not detected? How to detect them? It is a bug? ... ? All related but different

Comment: btw neither pthreads nor `malloc` or raw `new` are necessary in c++. The leaks in this code are leaks that can be fixed easily even without valgrind

Comment: And what is the output of your valgrind run?

Answer (score 2):

The allocations written in your program are not part of its observable behavior. The compiler is then free to optimize them away. Here is a live demo, where neither `malloc` nor `operator new` is ever called in the generated machine code:

https://godbolt.org/z/oG788ebTx

Comment: But this is with ``-O3``. With ``gcc  -Wall -pedantic -g valgrind.cpp -o vlgrnd -pthread -lstdc++`` these calls should not be optimized away, should they?

Comment: @ChristianHalaszovich Generally, it's up to the implementation of which optimizations are performed. For instance, non-guaranteed copy elision is usually applied even with disabled optimizations. But I agree that this is likely not the OP's case.